# Tkinter to excel data

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Tkinter app that takes input and outputs excel data.

I cannot get the entry for size or any other entry field. I tried many things but I haven't been able to get the entry so that it can then be saved into an excel file.

What changes can I make to my code to be able to get the entry once the user selects chair or table?

At the end I want the entry to be obtained and stored in the excel file when the user selects finish order.

```
import datetime    
import tkinter as tk
import xlwt as xl

from datetime import datetime

style1 = xl.XFStyle()
style1.num_format_str = "D-MM-YY"

wb = xl.Workbook()

sheet1 = wb.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
sheet1.write(0, 0, datetime.now(), style1)

sheet1.write(0, 1, "Item")
sheet1.write(0, 2, "Size")
sheet1.write(0, 3, "Quantity")

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Furniture order")

item_label = tk.Label(text="Select your item ")
item_label.grid(column= 5, row=0)

class Order:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def option (self):
        item_label.destroy()
        table_button.destroy()
        chair_button.destroy()

        size_label = tk.Label(text="Enter the size")
        size_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        color_label = tk.Label(text="Enter the color")
        color_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        quantity_label = tk.Label(text="Enter the quantity")
        quantity_label.grid(column=0, row=2)

        size_entry = tk.Entry()
        size_entry.grid(column=2, row=0)
        color_entry = tk.Entry()
        color_entry.grid(column=2, row=1)
        quantity_entry = tk.Entry()
        quantity_entry.grid(column=2, row=2)

        done_button = tk.Button(text="Finish the order", command=chair_data)
        done_button.grid(column=1, row=4)

    def get_entry (self):
        chair = Order("Chair")
        size = chair.option()
        size = size.size_entry.get()
        return size

def run_option ():
    chair = Order("Chair")
    chair.option()

def chair_data ():
    chair = Order("Chair")
    size = chair.get_entry()
    sheet1.write(1, 1, "table")
    sheet1.write(1, 2, size)

chair_button = tk.Button(text="Chair", command=run_option)
chair_button.grid(column=0, row=3)

table_button = tk.Button(text="Table", command=run_option)
table_button.grid(column=10, row=3)

wb.save("test2.xls")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: "I have tried many things" Like what?

Comment: Like the code you are seeing but it doesn't work

Comment: When I press the button in the excel sheet table is written but not the input value of the size